# find driverObject from module address using windbg kernel mode debugging

Tags: kernel, windbg, remote-debugging

I have the module address of a loaded driver. I want to get the driverobject from the module address or name using windbg in kernel mode debugging. Is there a command to find it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall if there's a list of driver objects accessible from a kernel global variable, so this is rather involved.

In Windbg you can query a list of all object (known to the object manager) with [`!object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/-object). This command, with the `path` option, allows you to query the `\driver` folder in the object manager to list all `_DRIVER_OBJECT`, for ex.:

```
0: kd> !object \driver
Object: ffff9c0a5dd51920  Type: (ffffe58ca0c8cd20) Directory
    ObjectHeader: ffff9c0a5dd518f0 (new version)
    HandleCount: 0  PointerCount: 105
    Directory Object: ffff9c0a5dc24420  Name: Driver

    Hash Address          Type                      Name
    ---- -------          ----                      ----
     00  ffffe58ca160ce00 Driver                    fvevol
         ffffe58ca0c9be20 Driver                    vdrvroot
     01  ffffe58ca15e8e00 Driver                    NetBT
         ffffe58ca0cc6e30 Driver                    acpiex
         ffffe58ca0d69df0 Driver                    Wdf01000
     02  ffffe58ca6ce8e30 Driver                    WdNisDrv
         ffffe58ca0c8e060 Driver                    mpsdrv
    
     // ... snip ...
```

Problem is that it's not scriptable at all since you'll want to traverse the whole list (edit: the module base of a driver is given in `_DRIVER_OBJECT.DriverStart`)

The object manager root lies at the global `nt!ObpRootDirectoryObject` but it's a pain in the back to parse...

Hugsy made a [really nice JS script](https://github.com/hugsy/windbg_js_scripts/blob/main/scripts/ObjectExplorer.js) to parse it, and fortunately it supports the `\driver` entry.

0. Download the script :)
1. Load the script: e.g. `.scriptload "C:\test\ObjectExplorer.js"`
2. Query all driver objects

```
dx -r0 @$drvs = @$cursession.Objects.Children.Where( obj => obj.Name == "Driver" ).First().Children.Select( obj_entry => obj_entry.NativeObject)
```

Note : if you want to see how the scripts encapsulates the objects, you can just do:

```
dx -r0 @$drvs = @$cursession.Objects.Children.Where( obj => obj.Name == "Driver" ).First().Children
```

3. Filter driver objects with the module base you have, e.g.: (obviously replace the `0xfffff8073a2d0000` address with your own)

```
0: kd> dx -g @$drvs.Where( drv => drv.DriverStart == 0xfffff8073a2d0000 )
===========================================================================================================================================================================================
=                              = [<Raw View>] = (+) HardwareDatabase                                         = (+) DeviceObject                                 = (+) Flags = (+) Devices =
===========================================================================================================================================================================================
= [0x0] : Driver "\Driver\CNG" - {...}        - 0xfffff80736355710 : "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPT... - 0xffffe58ca0d7ac10 : Device for "\Driver\CNG"    - 0x12      - {...}       =
===========================================================================================================================================================================================
```

You can then click on the entries, it outputs the full `_DRIVER_OBJECT` (or you can just `dt` the address):

```
0: kd> dx -r1 (*((ntkrnlmp!_DRIVER_OBJECT *)0xffffe58ca0c8ec10))
(*((ntkrnlmp!_DRIVER_OBJECT *)0xffffe58ca0c8ec10))                 : Driver "\Driver\CNG" [Type: _DRIVER_OBJECT]
    [<Raw View>]     [Type: _DRIVER_OBJECT]
    HardwareDatabase : 0xfffff80736355710 : "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM" [Type: _UNICODE_STRING *]
    DeviceObject     : 0xffffe58ca0d7ac10 : Device for "\Driver\CNG" [Type: _DEVICE_OBJECT *]
    Flags            : 0x12
    Devices         
0: kd> dx -r1 -nv (*((ntkrnlmp!_DRIVER_OBJECT *)0xffffe58ca0c8ec10))
(*((ntkrnlmp!_DRIVER_OBJECT *)0xffffe58ca0c8ec10))                 : Driver "\Driver\CNG" [Type: _DRIVER_OBJECT]
    [+0x000] Type             : 4 [Type: short]
    [+0x002] Size             : 336 [Type: short]
    [+0x008] DeviceObject     : 0xffffe58ca0d7ac10 : Device for "\Driver\CNG" [Type: _DEVICE_OBJECT *]
    [+0x010] Flags            : 0x12 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x018] DriverStart      : 0xfffff8073a2d0000 [Type: void *]
    [+0x020] DriverSize       : 0xbd000 [Type: unsigned long]
    [+0x028] DriverSection    : 0xffffe58ca0c6dd50 [Type: void *]
    [+0x030] DriverExtension  : 0xffffe58ca0c8ed60 [Type: _DRIVER_EXTENSION *]
    [+0x038] DriverName       [Type: _UNICODE_STRING]
    [+0x048] HardwareDatabase : 0xfffff80736355710 : "\REGISTRY\MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM" [Type: _UNICODE_STRING *]
    [+0x050] FastIoDispatch   : 0x0 [Type: _FAST_IO_DISPATCH *]
    [+0x058] DriverInit       : 0xfffff8073a384010 : cng!GsDriverEntry+0x0 [Type: long (__cdecl*)(_DRIVER_OBJECT *,_UNICODE_STRING *)]
    [+0x060] DriverStartIo    : 0x0 : 0x0 [Type: void (__cdecl*)(_DEVICE_OBJECT *,_IRP *)]
    [+0x068] DriverUnload     : 0x0 : 0x0 [Type: void (__cdecl*)(_DRIVER_OBJECT *)]
    [+0x070] MajorFunction    [Type: long (__cdecl* [28])(_DEVICE_OBJECT *,_IRP *)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow !object \driver did not show my driver. Don't know the exact reason.
Could manage some workaround. Since I knew the module address, debugged till driverEntry.First parameter to DriverEntry is the DriverObject. I was able to dump it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of driver
Then you can use

```
!drvobject drivername flag
```

If you have an address you can use

```
lm a address
```

to get the module name and use the module name in drvobj to get the details

[image]